# How twitter updates retweets and favorites without refreshing the page

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

Does anyone who use the current version of twitter right now know what they used to update retweets and favorites without having the user refresh the page? Or does anyone at least know how i can do this with swift? Would think be possibly by using ajax on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get that working. You can run an script that every second hits an url and gets the new retweets and stats, and updates the info on the page.
There is something about a relatively new technology called [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/), that provides a different way to connect two devices through the web (RTC stands for Real Time Communication).
Of course, you can use some ready plugins, or maybe some frameworks that are proper to do that work, with no pain, but the ideal is that you know how these things works under the hood first.
I hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks man! i appreciate your input. i never understood why people on this website down vote questions. Like isn't this about helping other people?

Comment: Same. I would love if people who down vote things (and up vote too, sometimes) explain why did they do it.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes but you should backup your answer with citations/links/evidence to prove your hypothesis. As it stands now, it's just an opinion/theory.

Comment: Good tip, thank you, but what about his question? Why did they down vote it?